# Day & Night Cycle Whilst Paused?

Tags: stardew-valley

Whilst I know that time can be stopped in-game when you're paused in a menu in Single-Player, it has been drawn to my attention that when immersed in a dialogue with an NPC, the 'Paused' option appears on the right hand side. The way I understand it, should this not also stop the time cycle?

I have, in a previous save, left my screen in an NPC dialogue, whilst apparently 'paused' and come back to it to find myself back at the house with a gold deduction and extra days passed on the calendar.

According to a post on [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/487877107144053651/#c487877107146364429) website, by Sirithre, time should in fact stop, when engaged in NPC activity.

Could someone please clarify as to whether this is intentional or if it is indeed a bug when it specifies 'paused' in a dialogue with an NPC?

Comment: If it says paused then it's definitely a bug. YI'd report this to the developer. not sure on the official channel, but he's active on both reddit and twitter (and posting it on reddit might have a few other users chime in with the same problem)

Comment: I have posted it on Reddit. I'll update this question if I can get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Reference For Future Viewers:***

So having spoken with the developer, this was indeed a bug and has now been patched.

Since updating the game, I am no longer having the issue.